# Referrer restrictions and localhost

Tags: youtube-api

I have a page where I am using swfobject and invoking the API's to control the youtube player.

When I run the application:

If the address is the local server (localhost) I can see all videos.

If I change the URL to my 192 internal address I get hit with the deadly restriction fail if these videos are marked as per the white and blacklists.

This seems like cheating but if I were to have a http server running on each client would this be illegal?  If I could spin up an instance Cassini and now localhost solves the referrer issue.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I run into the same problem and did some testing...
It seems, that Youtube restricts referers which consists of IP-Adresses.
For example, `http://localhost/` works perfectly fine, no restrictions whatsoever, but with `http://127.0.0.1/`, bam, you're getting screwed.

Try putting

```
127.0.0.1 test.asd
```

into your hosts-file and surf to `http://test.asd/`. Should work fine.

So... what this means is, get yourself a domain (probably dyndns?) and everything should be fine.